# Assign current value of a JSONObject to another JSONObject

Tags: java, json, compare

**General update:** I previously asked if I could get the value of a JSONObject as is, to later on compare it with an overwritten version of it. My first attempt was:

```
JSONObject oldObj = new JSONObject();
public void addRootNode(String nodeid, int depth) {
    oldObj = obj;
    //Get value of obj as is
    addNodesToGraph(nodeid, depth);
    //Change value of obj
}

//later
public boolean compareJSON(){
    return oldObj.equals(obj);
    //should return false
}
```

Altough I knew I'd only make a reference to `obj` by assigning `oldObj` to `obj` and not add it it's value. I was wondering if there was a method like `valueOf()` for JSON. 
I already got answears which helped me to get closer to the solution, but yet didn't solve it. For `org.simple.json` is there a possibility to get `oldObj` having the current value of `obj` to compare them later on and determinate the diference?
Right now I can't look into the class `org.simple.json.JSONObject` myself since the source is missing.
As reference: `org.json.JSONObject` could solve it with this constructor:
`public JSONObject(JSONObject jo, java.lang.String[] names)`. But doesn't provide other functionalities I need.

Comment: You're assigning the `obj`'s value to `oldObj` and printing both, so obviously `toJSONString` will print the same value.

Comment: Do you know the difference between objects and references in Java?

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm currently only assigning `oldObj` to `obj`. I was wondering if there was an option like `valueof()` or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject oldObj = obj
```

I think this doesn't do what you think it does. You are assigning a new reference to, rather than creating a new object with the values in obj.

You could use the constructor specified here:
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28org.json.JSONObject,%20java.lang.String[]%29 to copy the old values to a new object, but you have to specify all the keys that need to be copied.

Comment: According to the doc `public JSONObject(JSONObject jo,
                  java.lang.String[] names)` should do the job, but I get this error `The constructor JSONObject(JSONObject, String[]) is undefined`

Comment: What's the package name for the JSONObject class you're using?

Comment: `org.json.simple` I'm now trying to find the source to see if this constructor exists.

Comment: It's a different JSONObject altogether github.com/fangyidong/json-simple .. this doesn't have a means of copying via a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Eclipse or NetBeans or other IDE Debug option!
They have a variable tab and you can preview each value.

Comment: I'm not trying to debug it, I want to get the difference later

Comment: Its a JSONObject so you can get(String key) or get(Object key). 
You cant just valueOf() because json can have many elements.